# Thread poll count in log exceed than pool size

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

in Springboot application Thread count is growing than configured threadpool size. is the any reason for that

```
2021-09-30 13:45:25.595  INFO 21960 --- [  executor2-243] com.example.demo.Service2                
2021-09-30 13:45:25.595  INFO 21960 --- [  executor2-255] com.example.demo.Service2
```

Folwing is the thread pool configs

```
@Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor2() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(5);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

Comment: Note that the sequence numbers in the thread names do not necessarily mean there are 255 active threads at the moment. Your application could have been creating and removing threads all the time and each new thread would get a new id to make it unique (especially helpful for logging).

Comment: @Thomas But I have scene thread number repeat in some applications upto core or max pool size.

Comment: Well, it depends on the pool settings and usage. In your case any thread that's idle for 5 seconds will be terminated (until only 5 core threads remain) and if there are more tasks coming in the executor might create new threads. In other cases threads might not be idle for long enough and thus they aren't terminated.

Comment: You could also have a look at `CustomizableThreadCreator` which is a super class of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. It has a field `threadCount` which is only ever incremented if a new thread name is needed, i.e. that's the behavior I described in my first comment. `threadCount` doesn't mean "number of active threads" but "number of created threads" (the class is called `...ThreadCreator` after all).